# How can I adjust the sequential numbering scheme when exporting Photos?

Tags: photos

I'm trying to export ~200 or so photos from Photos.app to setup on a digital picture frame. These photos are in an album, in sequence, and I can export them in numbered order from Photos.

However, Photos exports using the following format:

"Filename - 1"
"Filename - 2"
...
"Filename - 10"
"Filename - 11"

etc.

My digital frame does not understand that 10 does not come before 2, so it plays back as 1,10,11,12...20,21

This *ought* to be solvable by having the Photos export using a format of 001,002,003, etc. I'm pretty sure iPhoto used to even let me do this! But I can't find any option to do so in Photos.

Is it possible to export using a sensible number order that my frame will understand?

Comment: If nobody is aware of a solution for Photos there is always the option of renaming then via Terminal.

Comment: Would you be happy to rename the contents of output directory like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754/how-to-zero-pad-numbers-in-file-names-in-bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After exporting files into a new folder, go to Finder, open that folder, and select all the photos you want to rename. Once they are selected, right-click on your selection and you'll see an option to "rename xx files" where xx is the number of files to rename. Click that option and you can input the files name and sequential number. Below shows the panel you get when you select 9 files and right-click on the files.

[image]

Now when you click on "Rename 9 items you get the panel shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Select the **photos** to *export* and then press: **⇧⌘E**

In the **Export** *sheet*, select the **Photo Kind:** and then select **Sequential** for **File Name:**, while leaving **Sequential Prefix:** blank, and **Subfolder Format:** to **None**.

Click the **Export** button.

Select a **location** for the **photos** to be exported to and click the **Export** button.

For the number of photos you mentioned, "~200", this will take a little while.

When the exporting is finished, then in **Terminal** *change directory* to the location of the exported photos.

```
cd /path/to/exported/photos
```

They will be named e.g. 1.png, 2.png, etc.

Use the following *compound command* to rename the files for a *three digit zero padded filename*.

```
for f in [0-9]*\.*; do mv -v -n "$f" "$(printf %03d "${f%.*}")"."${f##*.}"; done
```

The files will now be named e.g. 001.png, 002.png, etc.

Comment: This... works, but it fails the “teach Dad how to do this and not have to help him every time forevermore” test really really hard. :/

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz, I saw no requirement in the OP that _dad needs to be taught anything so you wouldn't have to keep doing thing for him_! My answer has the steps necessary to achieve what you were asking for, so I'm not sure what more you want.

Comment: Sure. And I’ll take any solution that works; I’m just noting what would make for an even better one.